# setuptools searching for false dependency

Tags: python, linux, setuptools, pywin32

I am running into a bizarre problem where I try to install my python package (using setuptools) on a Linux system and it tries to install pywin32 as a dependency. This **only** happens if I run it from a specific directory. If I move the whole tree to a different directory, it installs fine.

My setup.py does reference pywin32 for win32 platforms, but even when I remove this it makes no difference. I've also removed all the other requirements without any change in behavior. My setup.py has nothing in it other than setuptools initialization and a call to setup().

I have a virtualenv active and have tried switching to a new clean virtualenv without a change in behavior. I see the following when I run `setup.py develop`:

```
python setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
deleting foo.egg-info/requires.txt
writing foo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to foo.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to foo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'foo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /home/user/foo-env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo.egg-link (link to .)
foo 1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /home/user/magicdirectory/magic
Processing dependencies for foo==1.0
Searching for pywin32
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32/
Reading http://sf.net/projects/pywin32
```

Now, I may have accidentally tried to install a win32 egg of this package at some point, but that was in the original virtual environment and I can't figure out what it could have done to cause this.

How do I debug this? Where else could setuptools be searching for dependencies from?

**UPDATE**: It appears that it's not the name of the directory that matters, but where it is. If I move the package directory up one level, it will install fine. The directory in question here has been deleted and recreated multiple times so it doesn't appear to be related to anything inside the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *.egg-info in the dist develop directory.  If that doesn't work, try starting with a fresh, untouched checkout of your code without any of the other setuptools/dist artifacts and see if that reproduces the problem.  If it doesn't then you know it's one of the setuptools/dist artifacts that just needs to be cleaned up.